# Node.js: escaping spaces when executing a unix command

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping

Im using this command to compress files in node.js:

```
var command = '7z a ' + dest + ' ' + orig;
exec( command, function(err, stdout, stderr) { ...});
```

The problem comes when a file has spaces like `7z a my vacation.zip my vacation.pdf`

How could I escape dest and orig?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(dest)` should do it

Answer (score 3):

Try to use spawn:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('ls', ['-l', '/tmp/test with spaces']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });
```